# how to write spring boot backend delete operation for master detail crud using spring boot and angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am using 2 tables one for master and the other for details I need to do operation when I delete from the master table corresponding data of detail table also need to be deleted
table names are job and job parameter
I m using this mapping right now but only delete from one table how to add another table

```
@DeleteMapping("BatchJobDelete/{BatchJobId}") 
void DeleteBatchJOb(@PathVariable("BatchJobId") Long BatchJobId) {  
    createBatchJobService.deletByBatchJobId(BatchJobId); 
}
```

this is my backend code hop you find usefull
https://github.com/Shailesh11232/smartbatchjob-master/tree/main/SpringBoot/smartbatchjobui/smartbatchjobui/src/main/java/com/smartbatchjobui/smartbatchjobui

Comment: @DeleteMapping("BatchJobDelete/{BatchJobId}")
    void  DeleteBatchJOb(@PathVariable("BatchJobId")Long BatchJobId){
        createBatchJobService.deletByBatchJobId(BatchJobId);
    }

Comment: using this code for back end now

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please take your time and update your question with more information e.g. post your code of your Entities (the ones with the master-detail relation in database), `createBatchJobService` etc. Otherwise community members wont be able to help you.

Comment: Cascade delete is the one i guess you are looking for -> deleting one entity has to delete related entity. documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLJPA/a_cascadeondelete.htm#TLJPA351

Comment: https://github.com/Shailesh11232/smartbatchjob-master/tree/main/SpringBoot/smartbatchjobui/smartbatchjobui/src/main/java/com/smartbatchjobui/smartbatchjobui

Comment: this is my springboot backend code